# "got to have" in a sentence

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

Is the following sentence right:

"You got to have that satisfaction to never being satisfied"

English is not my first language and a friend of mine wants this as a tattoo. I can't shake the feeling that he will be walking around with a wrong sentence the rest of his life

Comment: This must be migrated to http://ell.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Upvote for being concerned with his friend.

Comment: It's definitely not grammatical, but it's a tattoo. The wording may have sentimental meaning, and I'd clear that up with your friend first.

Comment: @tylerharms The words do not have any sentimental value at all. He is a "bodybuilder" (and I take that term loosely). He just wants something that says: I am never satisfied with my body. And just like people that have a chinese tattoo wich says "Eggroll" in stead of "inner peace" I want to protect my friend from walking around with rubbish

Comment: Tattoos aint no grammar nazis.

Comment: Should be on English Language Learners

Comment: 'got to have' is generally considered poor construction.  The sentence is also fairly long for a tattoo.  I'd try a simple phrase instead.  Maybe something like "Striving for perfection" or something similar, implying that perfection is unreachable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with it is not grammatical. To make it thus you would need to say

> You have got to have that satisfaction of never being satisfied

And I also think 'that' should be changed to 'the'. The reason for my uncertainty is that the whole sentence sounds paradoxical. Can you be 'satisfied with never being satisfied'? Surely it can only happen if you are using 'satisfy' in different registers. And I am not at all clear that this is the case.

Comment: Thanks alot, I have to agree that it sounds a bit silly. But who am I to judge his choice of bodyart.

Comment: WS2 answer is perfect but maybe the inscription could be shortened to: **Be satisfied with being unsatisfied**. (Somebody save this man's skin!)

Comment: I agree that the end of the sentence should read "of never being satisfied" (or, alternatively, "to never be satisfied"), but **not** "to never being satisfied" – most certainly not on a tattoo of all things.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  I think you have perfectly hit upon what the 'tattooee' is wanting to say. But whilst a philosophical outlook can be a great strength in life, I agree this does carry a hint of resignation, and it troubles me.